# Extract values from a textbox to show in an option value

Tags: php, select, field

Hello I have a box with values 2012-21-04. What I would like to do is use 3 select options to display year, month, and day. I would use php to extract each value. How would i approach this?

Comment: Tring to understand but i guess we need some example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you always have the same type of string to work with, just split the strings, using "-" as delimiter:

```
$arr_date = explode("-",$date); // $date being "2012-21-04"
```

$arr_date will be an array of three elements containing the three seperated numerical values

Regards,
STEFAN